# Best way to get percentage counts in Polars

Tags: python-polars

I frequently need to calculate the percentage counts of a variable. For example for the dataframe below

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"person": ["a", "a", "b"], 
                   "value": [1, 2, 3]})
```

I want to return a dataframe like this:

| person | percent |
| --- | --- |
| a | 0.667 |
| b | 0.333 |

What I have been doing is the following, but I can't help but think there must be a more efficient / polars way to do this

```py
n_rows = len(df)

(   
    df
    .with_column(pl.lit(1)
    .alias('percent'))
    .groupby('person')
    .agg([pl.sum('percent') / n_rows])
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`polars.count`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.count.html) will help here.  When called without arguments, `polars.count` returns the number of rows in a particular context.

```py
(
    df
    .groupby("person")
    .agg([pl.count().alias("count")])
    .with_columns((pl.col("count") / pl.sum("count")).alias("percent_count"))
)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────┬───────┬───────────────┐
│ person ┆ count ┆ percent_count │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---           │
│ str    ┆ u32   ┆ f64           │
╞════════╪═══════╪═══════════════╡
│ a      ┆ 2     ┆ 0.666667      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b      ┆ 1     ┆ 0.333333      │
└────────┴───────┴───────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Series` [method](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.value_counts.html) `.value_counts`:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'person': ['a', 'a', 'b', None, 'b'],
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
})
```

```py
df['person'].value_counts(sort=True).select(
    pl.col('person'),
    pl.col('counts'),
    (pl.col('counts')/pl.col('counts').sum() * 100).round(2).alias('perc')
)
```

Or

```py
df['person'].value_counts(sort=True).select(
    pl.col('person'),
    pl.col('counts'),
    pl.col('counts').apply(lambda x: x/df.shape[0]*100).round(2).alias('perc')
)
```

Both will return:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬──────┐
│ person ┆ counts ┆ perc │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---  │
│ str    ┆ u32    ┆ f64  │
╞════════╪════════╪══════╡
│ a      ┆ 2      ┆ 40.0 │
│ b      ┆ 2      ┆ 40.0 │
│ null   ┆ 1      ┆ 20.0 │
└────────┴────────┴──────┘
```