# Possible to calculate counts and percentage in one chain using polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

From seeing some of the other polars answers it seems most things can be complete in a single chain. Is that possible with the below example? Any simplifications possible?

```
import polars as pl
scores = pl.DataFrame({
    'zone': ['North', 'North', 'North', 'South', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'East'],
    'score': [78, 39, 76, 56, 67, 89, 100, 55]
})

cnt = scores.groupby("zone").count()
cnt.with_column(
    (100 * pl.col("count") / pl.col("count").sum())
    .round(2)
    .cast(str)
    .str.replace("$", "%")
    .alias("perc")
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed the post below just after asking this question. Feel free to close as needed.

[Best way to get percentage counts in Polars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72747398/best-way-to-get-percentage-counts-in-polars)

```
(
    scores.groupby("zone")
    .agg([pl.count().alias("count")])
    .with_column(
        (pl.col("count") * 100 / pl.sum("count"))
        .round(2)
        .cast(str)
        .str.replace("$", "%")
        .alias("perc")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ zone  ┆ count ┆ perc  │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ u32   ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ South ┆ 1     ┆ 12.5% │
│ North ┆ 3     ┆ 37.5% │
│ East  ┆ 4     ┆ 50.0% │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

EDIT: Slightly simpler/cleaner version

```
(
    scores.groupby("zone")
    .agg(pl.count().alias("count"))
    .with_column(
        pl.format(
            "{}%",
            (pl.col("count") * 100 / pl.sum("count")).round(2)
        ).alias("perc")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ zone  ┆ count ┆ perc  │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ u32   ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ North ┆ 3     ┆ 37.5% │
│ South ┆ 1     ┆ 12.5% │
│ East  ┆ 4     ┆ 50.0% │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Storing percentages as string is expensive. I'd recommend storing them as fraction instead.

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to close it, just mark your answer as accepted.  @ritchie46 I'd assume they aren't storing this table but trying to make a table to present somehow but when you say store as fractions do you mean decimal (float) or having one int column for numerator and another for denominator?

Comment: By storing I meant storing in memory. I think a percentages column should have a float dtype.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Table would indeed be for display only.

Comment: @ritchie46 Thanks (bedankt) for creating polars. Love it!